# Help synonymize [jquery-tools] and [jquerytools]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I noticed that both [jquerytools](/questions/tagged/jquerytools) and [jquery-tools](/questions/tagged/jquery-tools) exist. I have proposed that [jquerytools](/questions/tagged/jquerytools) be a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-tools/synonyms) of [jquery-tools](/questions/tagged/jquery-tools). Could those who are able vote on the suggested synonym?

Comment: The one with the hyphen in it should be the master.  That is the generally-accepted format, and there are only 13 or so questions tagged [jquerytools].

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's how I suggested it, unless I screwed something up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed: [jquerytools](/questions/tagged/jquerytools) --> [jquery-tools](/questions/tagged/jquery-tools)